# Facebook connect with codeigniter redirect in loop after login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am trying to connect facebook using codeigniter. If i am connecting fist time,then I can see permission popup but after I authorise permission i am getting multiple redirect loop error.

If I am already logged in and authorised site then why it is not getting uid.

I have give site url in facebook: http://mysite.com/

and my redirect uri is http://mysite.com/facebook/

I have added these files in my library folder.

```
library/fb_connect.php
library/facebook/facebook.php
library/facebook/base_facebook.php
library/facebook/fb_ca_chain_bundel.crt
```

Last 3 files in facebook folder are facebook SDK files.

Here is code in my fb_connect.php

```
<?php
include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

 class Fb_connect {


function connect(){


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'cookie' => true,
 ));

    //Get User ID
  $user=$facebook->getUser();

  if(!$user){
   $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/beta/facebook/',
    'display'=> 'popup'
    ));

    redirect($loginUrl')";
    exit();


 } else {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

 print_r($user_profile);

}
 ?>
```

And Here is my controller code:

```
function  facebook(){

  $this->load->library('fb_connect');
  $user_data=$this->fb_connect->connect();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things;

1.You said "and my redirect uri is http://mysite.com/facebook/" - but in your code:

```
'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/beta/facebook/',
```

Should be:

```
'redirect_uri'  => 'http://mysite.com/facebook/',
```

2.You said "I have give site url in facebook: http://mysite.com/" - you need to specifically set the return URL in your facebook api aswell - should be "http://mysite.com/facebook"

3.You said your redirect is "http://mysite.com/facebook/" - have you set this as a route? Because normally it should be "http://mysite.com/mycontroller/facebook/"

4.You have a typo (if this is a copy + paste):

```
redirect($loginUrl')";
```

should be

```
redirect($loginUrl);
```

Comment: @Theshift.. First thanks for answer. About typo these are just mistakes as I modified a little bit code to make reader easier. So i changed redirect url, api and secret key, original code has no typo.So 1st and 4th point doesn't exits. I tried you 2nd point but same redirect.And answer of ur 4th point is yes i setup route. http://site.com/auth/facebook to site.com/facebook.

Comment: Just confirming your trying this on a live site and not a 'localhost'?